# Tilemap Index out of bounds collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision, scaling, bounds

I created my tile map and my player with movement.

I'm now trying to create the collision and I feel i'm on the right track.

Here is how I've created the map.

```
    List<Texture2D> tileTextures = new List<Texture2D>();
    int tileWidth = 60;
    int tileHeight = 60;

    public int[,] Map = new int[,]
        {
            {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2},
            {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        };

  public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        int tileMapWidth = Map.GetLength(1);
        int tileMapHeight = Map.GetLength(0);

        for (int x = 0; x < tileMapWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < tileMapHeight; y++)
            {
                int textureIndex = Map[y, x];
                Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];

                spriteBatch.Draw(
                    texture,
                    source = new Rectangle(x *myTile.Width,
                        y * myTile.Height,
                        tileWidth,
                        tileHeight),
                    Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am checking the 2d array coords with this condition and checking to see if a specific tile is there, where I can then set my previous location if it is true.

I'm currently testing on 1 tile atm.

```
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        prevPosition = position;
        input(gameTime);

       if(tiles.Map[(int)playerPosition.X/60,(int)playerPosition.Y/60] == 1)
        {
            position = prevPosition;
        }
    }
```

However my player position keeps going out of the index bounds of the 2D array and I believe I need to scale it down so that it stops this, I've tried dividing the play coords by the width of the tiles but that hasn't worked.

If anyone can help me with the correct scaling I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Have you checked what values you are getting when you try this?  Also your Map is not 60x60 it's 4x10, which could cause a problem when you try to position your player there.

Comment: No I haven't checked I'm quite new to all of this and unsure how to check. I have also tried dividing by 10 and 4 and I get the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: do some googling and learn how to use the debugger for visual studio and the immediate window.  A lot of developing software is trying to figure out why something did something unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if your player's position is like -x,y or x,-y or maybe -x,-y. Yor approach might be better if you'd make a fuction like this one

```
public bool CollidesWithWall(int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || x > *matrix width* - 1) return false;
    if(y < 0 || y > *matrix height* -1) return false;
    if (Map[x,y] == 1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

and use it insead of the line `tiles.Map[(int)playerPosition.X/60,(int)playerPosition.Y/60]`

Or, if you need the type of tile returned

```
public int CollidesWithWall(int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || x > *matrix width* - 1) return -1;
    if(y < 0 || y > *matrix height* -1) return -1;
    return Map[x,y];
}
```

By doing it this way, you'll know if you stumbled upon a health potion (just set it's ID to like 3) or a wall (with ID of 1 or something, that's tottaly up to you) and if it is 0, it's empty space (or maybe -1). Notice that the "-1" part is totaly up to you. Just write down a list of id's that youll have and which items they present.

**Other suggestions**
Try `if(tiles.Map[(int)(playerPosition.X/60f),(int)(playerPosition.Y/60f)] == 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, what do you mean by matrix width and height? Is that referring to the map width and height?

Sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: that are dimensions of yout 'public int[,] Map', in your case: 10x4. when you create 'int [,]', you created a matrix of whole numbers, or integers. And something like this 'strig [,]' is a matrix of strings.

Comment: Even with this function which is nice and clean for collision and I really like it. I'm still left with the issue of going out of the array bounds. I need to somehow scale down the position of player coords so that they remain within the array bounds. even if I was to have a 50,50 array, I would go out of it within a few movements.

Comment: I can't see what you want to achieve. First, when is this error poping up? Is the problem coming up when you start the game or when your player goes out of the bounds? I also don't know if you implemented it the way I intended you to. Please provide more information so I can help you. **Edit** your calculation for converting player position to matrix of integers works fine unless players out of the map

Comment: I would like to achieve collision in the sense that when the play position hits a certain location containing a certain tile from the array that it will put the player back to his previous position. The error occurs when the player position becomes bigger than the array itself. Here is how I am implementing it.

       public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            prevPosition = position;
            input(gameTime);
            if(CollidesWithWall((int)position.X, (int)position.Y))
            {
                position = prevPosition;
            }

        }

Comment: Can you send me the specific line of code that error occures on? That would help a lot

Comment: The error occurs in the "tile.map[x,y]" saying that the index goes out of bounds, when the player position becomes too big and goes outside the array.

        public bool CollidesWithWall(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x < 0 || x > (10*60) -1) return true;
            if (y < 0 || y > (4*60) -1) return true;
            if (tiles.Map[x, y] == 1) return true;
            else return false;
        }

Comment: And it helped. You see, the *x* and *y* you send to function must be players position in the matrix, not its real coordinates. Yes, your tile is 60 in width, but in your matrix, your tile's width is 1. For all other tiles too. We have a saying in serbia, "don't mix frogs with grandmothers" (sounds better in serbian). **Short version:** instead of (4*60) and (10*60), simply put 4 and 10. **Explanation** the (x*60) is the *on screen* position of the tile, where *x* is the *matrixes* position of the tile. So eather compare matrix vs matrix position, or on screen vs on screen.

Comment: Thank you for your help this is beginning to make more sense to me.
I have changed them so they they are ints being compares with the array ints.
This has solved my issue of going out of bounds within the array, but the interaction with the tile doesn't seem to be registering.


public bool CollidesWithWall(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x < 0 || x > (20) -1) return false;
            if (y < 0 || y > (20) -1) return false;
            if (tiles.Map[x, y] == 1) return true;
            else return false;
        }

Comment: That is a different question than the one asked in the title. I know I requested a lot of you in the comments, but to be fair to other members of StackOverflow and follow its rules, please ask another question with what you explained now as the title. Also, it might be a good idea to include full code for your 'input(gameTime);' function, which will tell us how you actually move the player around the map. Also, if I answered your question, please mark it as the answer.